# How to make RFID reader seek for card continously

Tags: c#, rfid, writer, reader

For a while now, i have been trying to make my RFID reader to automatically read (scan) a card. Although the former code i had, makes the reader scan the card when a button is pressed. But i want to be able to scan cards automatically and continuously, once any card is placed in the field. Here is what i tried. but i was not able to display the scanned UID in a textbox. Please, your help will be appreciated.

```
 class CardReader : IDisposable
    {

        IntPtr _pSnr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);
        private Thread _t;
        private Action<string> _callback;
        private volatile bool _stop;

        public void ReadCard()
        {
            short icdev = 0x0000;
            int status;
            byte type = (byte)'A';//mifare one type is A 
            byte mode = 0x26;  // Request the card which is not halted.
            ushort TagType = 0;
            byte bcnt = 0x04;//mifare  hold on 4
            IntPtr pSnr;
            byte len = 255;
            sbyte size = 0;
            pSnr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                status = rf_request(icdev, mode, ref TagType);//request card  
                if (status != 0)
                    continue;

                status = rf_anticoll(icdev, bcnt, pSnr, ref len);//i did anticol--get the card sn
                if (status != 0)
                    continue;

                status = rf_select(icdev, pSnr, len, ref size);//select one card
                if (status != 0)
                    continue;

                byte[] szBytes = new byte[len];

                for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
                {
                    szBytes[j] = Marshal.ReadByte(pSnr, j);
                }

                String m_cardNo = String.Empty;

                for (int q = 0; q < len; q++)
                {
                    m_cardNo += byteHEX(szBytes[q]);
                }

                _callback(m_cardNo);

               // txtSearchPurse.Text = m_cardNo;

                break;
            }
        }

        public void Work()
        {
            while (!_stop)
            {
                ReadCard();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        public void Start(Action<string> cardRead)
        {
            if (_t != null)
                return;

            _stop = false;

            _callback = cardRead;

            _t = new Thread(Work);
            _t.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            if (_t != null)
            {
                _stop = true;
                _t.Join();
                _t = null;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(_pSnr);
        }
    }
```

And i tried to use it like this:

```
 private void btnRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {
     var reader = new CardReader();
     reader.Start(CardReaded);
}
private void CardReaded(string cardnr){
//txtSearchPurse.Text = _callback;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here is what i tried. but i was not able to display the scanned UID in a textbox.*

So your callback successfully fired?  What error, if any, did you get?  I'm guessing you got a "cross thread exception".  If so, fix it like this:

```
    private void CardReaded(string cardnr)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            txtSearchPurse.Text = cardnr;
        });        
    }
```

Comment: @ Idle_Mind. Please how can I make the card to be scanned only once, though the reader is seeking to Scan continuous. So cards are scanned just once no matter how long they stay on the reader. Thanks.

Comment: I've never actually used a reader myself.  Is there any documentation?  How about a way to detect when the card has left the field?  If not, I can't think of a **reliable** way other than to ignore notifications from the same "cardnr" for a set period of time.